# Magento2.2.5 remove default product title and add custom phtml file on product detail page

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, phtml

in Magento2.2.5 I want to remove the product name and instead where it is load a custom phtml file that will call in a custom product attribute

However my phtml file is not being called in here is my catalog_product_view.xml which I have in my custom design:-

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/magento_Category/layout

folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
    <move element="prev_next_products" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
    <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final"/>
    <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price"/>
    <move element="product.special.price" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price"/>

    <move element="product_view_try_on" destination="product.info.media" before="-"/>
    <referenceBlock name="product.attributes" remove="true" />
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product_custom_name" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/product_custom_name.phtml" before="product.info.price"/>

</body>
```

Comment: yo can directly change in title.phtml file , copy the title.phtml file to theme and do the changes you want

Answer (score 1):

You have put `catalog_product_view.xml` file in wrong location. You have to put that file in `app/design/frontend/your_theme/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout` folder. And put custom phtml file in `app/design/frontend/your_theme/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view` folder. If still your phtml file not calling then try to add your custom phtml file like following:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
       <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product_custom_name" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/product_custom_name.phtml" before="product.info.price"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Hope it works.